# Dont drop Parent node on its childnode when doing drag/drop

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, objectlistview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Book name="Book" UID="0" State="Checked">
  <Book1 name="Book1" UID="1" DataSourceId="1" State="Checked">
    <NoteBook name="NoteBook1" State="Checked" UID="3">
    </NoteBook>
    <NoteBook name="NoteBook2" State="Checked" UID="4">
    </NoteBook>              
  </Book1>
</Book>
```

I am doing drag drop operation so that I have select node Book1(Drag Node) and dropped on NoteBook2(Dropped Node) which invalid user action because parent is not child of its child.I need to validate if target node is not ancestor

```
 var sourceModels = e.SourceModels.Cast<XElement>();
                    XElement targetModels = e.TargetModel as XElement;

                    if (sourceModels.Any(x => targetModels.Ancestors("")//something like this
                        e.InfoMessage = "Cannot drop on descendant (think of the temporal paradoxes!)";
                    else
                        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
```

Comment: XElement doc = XElement.Load(FILENAME);
            string notebook = "NoteBook1";
            XElement book = doc.Descendants("Book1").Where(x => x.Elements("NoteBook").Select(y => (string)y.Attribute("Name") == notebook).Any()).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: sourceModels.Descendants().Contains(targetModels);

Comment: getting this error Unable to cast object of type 'System.Xml.XmlElement' to type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement'. when used sourceModels.Descendants().Contains(targetModels);